# CreateQuery with excluding NULL and empty String must both work in Oracle and mySQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, openjpa

I'm trying to get records in my Transaction table where the message is not empty and not null. It's working on my MySQL DB but it's not working in Oracle DB. Since I think Oracle is treating empty as null.

```java
public List<Transaction> getAllTransactions() {
    return getEntityManager()
            .createQuery("from Transaction as transaction where transaction.message != null AND transaction.message != ''", Transaction.class)
            .getResultList();
}
```

How can I make this work on both MySQL and Oracle?

Comment: Does the above query give you the correct output when using a DB client?

Comment: @ScaryWombat no. it only works on mysql.

Comment: Have you tried `transaction.message is not null AND...` instead?  That is standard JPQL and should work across all databases.

Comment: @AlexL. same thing.. I think the problem is Oracle doesnt recognize != <empty>.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/20c383d/9

Comment: != '' does not work with Oracle. You have to options. 1) make sure that you don't insert empty strings in MySQL that you can use only is null 2) you have to create separate queries.